# Unable to deploy VMSS in combination to ARM deployment

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I hope somebody can guide me with this issue. I do not have issues deploying resources via the web interface. This time I am trying to automatize my infrastructure and I am deploying via ARM. All the resources for the Service Fabric cluster I am trying to create are deployed with no issue, except for the VMSS which throws me this error:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "LinkedAuthorizationFailed",
        "message": "The client has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/deploy/action' on scope '/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourcegroups/AllyStage-v2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/StageNode', however the linked subscription 'xxxxx' was not found. "
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: a typo in kv resource id?

Comment: No, I already verified it. Additionally I checked the permissions for the key vault and that it has Azure Resource Manager for template deployment enabled and that my user has permissions. Does a ARM deployment inpersonates a weird principal?

Comment: are those in the same tenant?

Comment: @JoséFernándezAlameda Please also include your ARM template in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped to look at the ARM template that you're trying to deploy. However, I suspect the problem is that the resource ID for a resource or subscription isn't resolving correctly. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f03c1772-06a5-4130-911a-b016946d58f2/the-client-has-permission-to-perform-action-microsofteventgrideventsubscriptionswrite-on-scope?forum=AzureDataFactory) is a similar issue from the past.

Also, if you are deploying the ARM template from within another bash/PowerShell script, I suggest you ensure that you have the correct context/subscription set before initiating the template deployment, and verify the scope of permissions of the principal performing the deployment.